# can't connect to vulnserver using netcat

Tags: windows, vmware, netcat

I am not able to connect to vulnserver using netcat.
I type this to connect
`nc -nv 192.168.70.130 9999`

(UNKNOWN) [192.168.70.130] 9999 (?) open
and it says this forever and doesn't happen anything

I have disabled real time protection, allowed in firewall and also VM is set to NAT mode.

Is there any other way to connect or what might be the possible issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered the same issue. I thought it was my VM acting up, so I restarted the network access. I tried allowing vulnserver.exe through my windows firewall. Neither of them solved the issue. Finally, I disabled windows defender firewall and now it works like a charm. But before doing this, try to ping the windows machine from the linux box. If there's a response it should work. If there is no response however, try enabling file and printer sharing in windows. For more info, read this...https://superuser.com/questions/1137912/ping-to-windows-10-not-working-if-file-and-printer-sharing-is-turned-off

Answer (score 1):

**Immunity Debugger and vulnserver** has to run as *administrator*, then Immunity Debugger can see vulnserver, otherwise Im..Deb can't see because of *less privileged* then vulnserver.

Also we need **run** *Immunity Debugger*

Answer (score 0):

That's mean port 9999 has already been opened which is expected if you're already executed `vulnserver`

```
wolf@linux:~$ nc -nv 127.0.0.1 9999
(UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 9999 (?) open
Welcome to Vulnerable Server! Enter HELP for help.
```

It also means that you've already connected to the server. Go ahead and type HELP to see more info.

Try to setup using different network mode such as internal or host-only mode.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue - I'm not sure if you are using it in conjunction with Immunity Debugger like me (as part of an ethical hacking course) but I kept getting that situation because I forgot to hit 'play' on the debugger.